# NFC app keeps hanging after intent passed to new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I am still new to the concept of android programming. I am currently trying to develop a app which is able to read, write NFC tags.

However I cannot seem to find the hanging issue that is happening to my google Nexus, perhaps some experienced devs can point me to some light on this issue.

Firstly, I have a main activity, which has a pending intent to fire off once a nfc tag comes into range.

```
//main activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //blank tag intent
    blankIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayBlankTagActivity.class);
    //ndef tag intent
    homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayHomeActivity.class);

    //initialize nfc
    NfcManager manager = (NfcManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
    nfcAdapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
    nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // if tag is written
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
    // if blank tag
    else if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        startActivity(blankIntent);
    }
}

public void enableForegroundMode() {
    //Intent filters
    IntentFilter nDefTag = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        nDefTag.addType("text/plain");
    }catch(MalformedMimeTypeException e){}
    IntentFilter blankTag = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter[] tagFilters = new IntentFilters[]{nDefTag, blankTag);
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, tagFilters, null);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    enableForegroundMode();
}
```

My blank tag intent is working fine, it is simply a form to fill in with simple editboxes.
My home intent view is simply a GridView with 3 by 3 image buttons and some fancy pictures.
The hang happens when the app detects a ndef tag, it is able to load the home intent content but when I press the back button on the Nexus, it hangs there. It seems to be stuck at (stack)

```
BinderProxy.transact
INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.setForegroundDispatch
NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch
MainActivity.enableForegroundMode
```

seems like enableForegroundDispatch is creating problems for me. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where do you call `MainActivity.enableForegroundMode()`? Post that code. Also explain what Activity you are in when you press the BACK button that causes the hang.

Comment: You should to the 'work' in the onResume method. Like so here https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools-util/src/org/ndeftools/util/activity/NfcDetectorActivity.java

Comment: the onResume method has the enableForegroundMode(). The program should be back at the main activity when i press the back button, although i do not know if it is working that way...

Comment: hi Thomas, thanks for the link, but could you show me an implementation example of how your activity classes?

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, have you got the disable foreground dispatch in onPause also setup in the mainactivity? If you don't properly disable it you wont be able to re-enable on return (back button).

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    super.onPause();
}
```